# multi style switch

Tags: php

Does anybody have a good way to switch styles in the admin section only to change the layout of the website.

Lets say I have 3 styles and I want to change the look of the website but want to do it in the admin section but the effect needs to happen on both admin and user end.

I want the admin to have access to change the styles only and not the end user but the effect is to be shown on both the admin section and the user end.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to put all the style dependent CSS rules into a single CSS file which you could swap output via PHP.

For example, if you can three "theme" styles ("loud.css", "brash.css" and "happy.css"), on each PHP page on the front end and back end you could simply output the HTML to include a single one of them based on the contents of a database setting.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the stylesheet you include a variable that you store in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Store the stylesheet value in a database and use it at header page render. Then you can write a simple admin tool to change its value.

Answer (score 0):

## style.php

```
$avail_styles = array("green","red","blue");

if(isset($_REQUEST['style']) && in_array($_REQUEST['style'],$avail_styles))
{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['style'] = $_REQUEST['style'];
    echo "1"; exit;
}
echo "0"; //No Changes
```

## javascript / jQuery

```
$("#style select").change(function(){
    val = $("option:selected",this).val();

    //Ping style.php
    $.get("style.php",{style:val},function(resonce){
        if(response == "1")
        {
            //Load the new style sheet or document.location to refresh
        }
    });
})
```

## index.php

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $_SESSION["style" ]?>.css" />
```

You should be able to see how this works but as im in a major rush so ill be able to add a more descriptive reply a little later, hope this helps.